# What is the proper way to sand live edge piece of wood in preparation for a polyurethane finish?

Tags: wood, woodworking, wooden-furniture

I have debarked a live edge walnut slab. Since the edge is rough and not flat, how would one properly sand that live edge without killing all of the subtle contours of that live edge. All of the sanding is being done to prepare for a polyurethane finish.

[image]
[image: walnut slab]

Comment: Why would you want to? I'd apply urethane until I had the texture I was after and leave the wood alone.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but wasn't sure if it's ok to apply poly directly to unsanded wood

Comment: Sand blast with pecan shell media

Answer (score 1):

The reasons to sand before applying finish are to scuff the surface to give the finish something to cling onto, clean the surface of any dirt in the fibers of the wood and to flatten any imperfections.  Poly will generally stick to a good clean surface that is as porous as wood.  I would just go over it with a wire brush to make sure it is clean and evenly scuffed.

Comment: I was going to say hit it with a stainless steel pad for a few mins... but you pretty much have same answer and from the looks of it a lot more background.